# 0-1 knapsack using python cplex

Tags: python, knapsack-problem, cplex, opl

I'm trying to solve a slight modification of a 0-1 knapsack problem, where each item is a vector of values from which one value is chosen, instead of a scalar using Python Cplex. This is a variant of a [Mixed integer problem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SS9UKU_12.4.0/com.ibm.cplex.zos.help/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/02_prob_statement.html). I wrote a [IBM OPL](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/modeling/) solution to this problem, but unable to figure out how to solve it using [Python Cplex](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.LinearConstraintInterface-class.html?cp=SSSA5P_12.6.0). My solution using IBM OPL is:

```
int Capacity = 100; // Capacity of the knapsack
int k = 2;   // Number of items
int n = 5;  // Number of values
range values = 1..n;
range items = 1..k;

// parameters
int profit[items][values] = [[ 5, 10, 20, 20, 20],  // only one item should be selected from this list
                             [ 5, 20, 25, 30, 40]]; // only one item should be selected from this list
int weight[values]        =  [ 10, 20, 50, 70, 80]; // Corresponding weights


// decision variable x[i][j]=1 if the jth item is selected
dvar boolean x[items][values];

// objective function
maximize sum(i in items, j in values) x[i][j] * p[i][j];

// constraints
subject to{

sum(i in items, j in values) x[i][j] * w[j] <= Capacity;
forall(i in items) sum(j in values) x[i][j] <= 1;

}
```

We can run this problem as `oplrun -v knapsack.mod`. The solution to this problem is

```
x = [[0 1 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 1]];
profit = 10 + 40
       = 50
```

The mathematical formulation of the problem is:

[image: Knapsack math formulation]

I'm trying to get the same solution I got above using Python CPLEX. The following code is my try to solve the problem but it is not correct. I'm unsure of how to solve it:

```
import cplex


capacity = 100  # Capacity of the cache
k = 2  # Number of items
n = 5  # Number values for each item
profit = [[5, 10, 20, 20, 20],
          [5, 10, 25, 30, 40]]
weight = [10, 20, 50, 70, 80]
xvar = []  # Will contain the solution


def setupproblem(c):
    c.objective.set_sense(c.objective.sense.maximize)

    # xvars[i][j] = 1 if ith item and jth value is selected
    allxvars = []
    for i in range(k):
        xvar.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            varname = "assign_" + str(i) + "_" + str(j)
            allxvars.append(varname)
            xvar[i].append(varname)

    # not sure how to formulate objective
    c.variables.add(names=allxvars, lb=[0] * len(allxvars),
                    ub=[1] * len(allxvars))

    # Exactly one value must be selected from each item
    # and the corresponding weights must not exceed capacity
    # Not sure about this too.
    for j in range(k):
        thevars = []
        for i in range(n):
            thevars.append(xvar[i][j])
        c.linear_constraints.add(
                    lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(thevars, [1] * len(thevars))],
                    senses=["L"],
                    rhs=capacity)


def knapsack():
    c = cplex.Cplex()

    setupproblem(c)
    c.solve()
    sol = c.solution

if __name__ == "__main__":
    knapsack()
```

Comment: Hey @Sunil even though I have no idea what a knapsack-problem is, this question seems interesting. There's a slight issue though, what problem are you facing exactly? Make it a bit more clear in your question, I don't like it when interesting-looking questions get closed as *Unclear what you're asking* when they could be easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you didn't indicate that the program you solve is MIP. I don't know how to work with 2d variables under Python, but the following works:

```
import numpy as np
import cplex
from cplex import Cplex
from cplex.exceptions import CplexError

capacity = 100  # Capacity of the cache
k = 2  # Number of items
n = 5  # Number values for each item
profit = [[5, 10, 20, 20, 20],
          [5, 10, 25, 30, 40]]
weight = [10, 20, 50, 70, 80]

xvar = [ [ 'x'+str(i)+str(j) for j in range(1,n+1) ] for i in range(1,k+1) ]
xvar = xvar[0] + xvar[1]
profit = profit[0] + profit[1]

types = 'B'*n*k

ub = [1]*n*k
lb = [0]*n*k

try:
    prob = cplex.Cplex()
    prob.objective.set_sense(prob.objective.sense.maximize)

    prob.variables.add(obj = profit, lb = lb, ub = ub, types = types, names = xvar )

    rows = [[ xvar, weight+weight ]]
    rows = [[ xvar, weight+weight ],
            [ xvar[:5], [1]*5 ],
            [ xvar[5:], [1]*5 ],
           ]

    prob.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr = rows, senses = 'LEE', rhs = [capacity,1,1], names = ['r1','r2','r3'] )

    prob.solve()
    print
    print "Solution value  = ", prob.solution.get_objective_value()
    xsol = prob.solution.get_values()
    print 'xsol = ', np.reshape(xsol, (k,n) )

except CplexError as exc:
    print(exc)
```

The answer I got:

```
Solution value  =  50.0
xsol =  [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
         [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Comment: There can be only one item selected from each of the list in  `profit`. That why I used `sum(i in items) max(j in values)` in OPL. How can I add this constraint in Python?

Comment: well, in that case you need to add the following constraints: sum(j, x_ij) == 1 for all i, to make sure that your condition is true.

Comment: I've edited the post, now it gives the right answer, but it's easy to check that in your OPL model the previous solution is optimal too. Indeed, `(x11+x21)*5 + (x12+x22)*10 + ... <= capacity`, no matter if x11=x21=1 or x12=1 and x22=0, we have the final weight 10 and the same profit=10+40=5+5+40=50.

Comment: I've added the math behind it in my question. `(x11+x21)*5 + (x12+x22)*10` can never occur because only one value can be selected per `item`(row) in `profits`. I'm still not sure where in your code that constraint is defined, but +1 for working example.Tthanks!

Comment: Looks like you need to solve a multi-objective knapsack problem. Can you write the original problem you are modeling as LP?

Comment: I didn't model it using LP. I'm very new to this. Correct me if I'm wrong, if I have modeled it using LP, couldn't I have just solved it using `cplex.solve(lp_modeled);`? Which will also work fine, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Apparently, there are "real-world" problems like traveling salesman or resource allocation problem that can be formulated (or modeled) as linear programs (it has nothing to do with cplex model). What was the problem you formulated in your OPL code? I'm asking as maximizing sums of max's looks strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96808/discussion-between-sunil-and-serge-k).