# prob.linear_constraints.add in clplex python syntax

Tags: python, api, syntax, cplex

[0-1 knapsack using python cplex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007864/0-1-knapsack-using-python-cplex)

I found this discussion very useful for learning the python-cplex API. However, I do not understand the meaning of the "senses" in the following command:

```
prob.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr = rows, senses = 'LEE', rhs = [capacity,1,1], names = ['r1','r2','r3'] )
```

What does the 'LEE' argument stand for exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The `'LEE'` stands for "less-than" (**<=**), "equality" (**=**), and "equality" (**=**). Each individual character represents the "senses" of the three constraints that are added to the problem.  If you exported the model in LP format, you'd see something like (these constraints are purely for example, not from the problem you mentioned):

```
r1: x1 + x2 + x3 <= 1.0
r2: x2 - 3 x5 = 2.0
r3: x7 + x8 = 10.0
```

See the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.LinearConstraintInterface-class.html?view=kc#add) for the Python API, and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/addrows.html) for the underlying function in the C API.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very useful!